# How can I delete ALL alarms in the stock Clock app?

Tags: stock-android, alarm, delete

How can I delete ALL alarms in the stock Clock app?

I see that you can delete them one-by-one, but I have 50+ (created regularly with voice commands), and I'd like to get rid of them in one action.

Answer (score 13):

I deleted all alarms in Android Jellybean 4.1.1 by performing the following operations in Settings > Apps > All > Clock:

Force stop
Clear data
Clear cache

YMMV

Comment: It's very disappointing that this seems to be the best option. Like you, I create a bunch of alarms through voice commands. What I want is a command that lets me delete all alarms that are turned off, since most of them are but I would like to leave the few that are not. Your cache clearing trick obviously doesn't work for this. Poor design by Android.

Comment: I wouldn't even understand that this option is missing if it were a niche app found in the depth of the google play store.. but the android stock clock? really?!

Answer (score 3):

Incredibly, this is still an unaddressed issue in 2022.
I have noticed that it's possible to ask google assistant to delete all of your **active** alarms -- meaning the ones that are scheduled to ring.

So one inconvenient way to deal with this, would be to activate all the alarms manually (which is a bit faster than deleting them manually) and then ask google assistant to 'delete all of my alarms'.

Careful btw: asking Google assistant to 'delete all of my inactive alarms', will actually delete only your active ones (which is how I discovered this).

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the page there is a garbage can. You can click on the can, which will show a multi select option, which lets you mark each alarm for deletion.

Comment: That can doesn't show up for me